# Code block working in mozilla firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox

Does anyone have any idea why this code block might work well in Mozilla Perfectly and not at all in Chrome? This code block is generating and presenting perfectly in Mozilla Firefox, but not at all in the Chrome search engine. This started when I placed some new code into the block starting at the x = -1 variable and below.

```
function displaySideBarLink( title, sectionname, anchorid) {

    let sidebar;

    if ($) {
        sidebar = $('#page-layout #record-sidebar .w3-container.menu-links');
    }

    if (sidebar) {
        // Create a link in the side bar navigation
        let sidebar_link = document.createElement("a");


        let section_title = title || sectionname;
        if (section_title) {
            sidebar_link.id = sectionname + "-sidebar";
            sidebar_link.className = "w3-bar-item";
            sidebar_link.href = '#' + anchorid;

            sidebar_link.title = section_title;
            sidebar_link.alt = section_title;
            sidebar_link.innerText = section_title;


            sidebar.append(sidebar_link);
        }

    }

    x = -1
    lastName = ""
    $("#panels-region .panel-heading").each(function () {
        x++
        console.log($(this))
        curName = $(this).attr("name")
        $('<a id="panels-sidebar-' + curName.replace(/ |\//g, "_") + '" class="w3-bar-item" href="#panel-' + x + '-header" title="' + curName.replace(/ |\//g, "_") + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ' + curName + '</a>').insertAfter("#panels-sidebar" + lastName.replace(/ |\//g, "_"))
        console.log($(this).attr("name"), lastName)
        lastName = "-" + curName
    })
    lastName = ""
    $("#graph-region .panel-heading h4").each(function () {
        try {
            x++
            console.log($(this).text())
            curName = $(this).text().replace("Collapse panelExpand panel", "")
            $('<a id="tree_viewers-sidebar-' + curName.replace(/ |\//g, "_") + '" class="w3-bar-item" href="#panel-' + x + '-header" title="' + curName.replace(/ |\//g, "_") + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ' + curName + '</a>').insertAfter("#tree_viewers-sidebar" + lastName.replace(/ |\//g, "_"))
            console.log($(this).attr("name"), lastName)
            lastName = "-" + curName
        } catch (e) {
        }
    })

    $(".menu-links a").css("padding", "0px 8px")

    $(".field-value").each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).text())
    })
    $("#tables-content td").each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).text())
    })
    $(".panel-body").css("background-color", "white")
    $("#panels-region .panel-wrapper .panel-default").css("background-color", "white")
}
```

Comment: "Chrome search engine" ???

Comment: So is there any errors in the developer console? Do any of the console lines execute?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
views.js:60 Failed to fetch user permissions, url = /query/web/api/v1/user

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.getPermissions is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (views.js:63)
    at fire (jquery.js:3099)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3211)
    at done (jquery.js:8266)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.js:8605)

Comment: jquery.js:8561 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
send @ jquery.js:8561
undefined.svg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: These are the current errors in chrome

Comment: These are the current errors in mozilla

Comment: Failed to fetch user permissions, url = /query/web/api/v1/user views.js:60
Uncaught TypeError: this.getPermissions is not a function
    existingRequest views.js:63
    jQuery 4
views.js:63
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience.

Comment: To add to this, the expected addition flashes and goes off of the screen.

Comment: So where is the Ajax call?

Comment: I had to find the place where the page was actually loaded and then place it. The issue was that the data was coming across as whole in html. This is the block where it was placed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function getRecordUI( alias, type, id, viewtype, version ) {

    // Get record model from Data Model Registry
    if ( type ) {
        getJSONUIModel( type,
            function ( data ) {
                displayRecordSections( alias, type, id, version, viewtype, data );
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("Error getting UI model for type " + type);
                console.log(error);
                displayRecordSections( alias, type, id, version, viewtype, null );
            });
    } else {
        displayRecordSections( alias, type, id, version, viewtype, null );
    }
    let x = -1;
    lastName = "";
    $("#panels-region .panel-heading").each(function () {
        x++

        console.log($(this))
        let curName = $(this).attr("name")
        $('<a id="panels-sidebar-' + curName.replace(/ |\//g, "_") + '" class="w3-bar-item" href="#panel-' + x + '-header" title="' + curName.replace(/ |\//g, "_") + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ' + curName + '</a>').insertAfter("#panels-sidebar" + lastName.replace(/ |\//g, "_"))
        console.log($(this).attr("name"), lastName)
        lastName = "-" + curName
    })

    $("#graph-region .panel-heading h4").each(function () {
        x++
        let x = -1;
        console.log($(this).text())
        let curName = $(this).text().replace("Collapse panelExpand panel", "")
        $('<a id="tree_viewers-sidebar-' + curName.replace(/ |\//g, "_") + '" class="w3-bar-item" href="#panel-' + x + '-header" title="' + curName.replace(/ |\//g, "_") + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ' + curName + '</a>').insertAfter("#tree_viewers-sidebar" + lastName.replace(/ |\//g, "_"))
        console.log($(this).attr("name"), lastName)
        lastName = "-" + curName
    })

    $(".menu-links a").css("padding", "0px 8px")
    $(".panel-body").css("background-color", "white")
    $("#panels-region .panel-wrapper .panel-default").css("background-color", "white")

}
```